# Socket communiction in absence of wired network connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, wired, sockets

I am facing a strange issue on my Ubuntu (12.04.3 64 bit). I have a couple of C programs communicating (let's call them sender and receiver programs) through sockets. These  work as expected when the machine (a dell laptop in this case) is connected to LAN.

But when I isolate the laptop from the LAN (which means the Wired Connection is disconnected as shown in Network Manager), I can no longer send/receive using sockets. Probably the communication goes through the network card which is not powered (my guess) in this case. Please suggest how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use loopback address "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" in that situation!﻿

Comment: Probably I didn't make it clear in my question, but I am using "multicast communication" using sockets. So I donot need an IP address to send to.

Comment: Okay, Thats a whole another issue in itself. I don't know much about that but you might look into similar questions about it. A simple google search brings up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180749/simulating-multicasting-on-loopback-interface. It basicly tells to use this `setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 0, 1);`